# botón-seleccionar no responde a evento click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Estoy realizando un programa en JS, y no me va una función a la cual llamó un botón **(boton-seleccionar) que posteriormente he creado con un innerHTML dentro de otra función**. He probado varias maneras de llamarlo, a traves de javascript vanilla, como Jquery, pero ni aún asi me funciona, el programa pasa por alto completamente la existencia de dicho botón, adjunto mi código a continuación, a ver si vosotros sois capaces en ver que estoy fallando porque yo en cambio no consigo verlo. Un saludo. Ajunto mi código javascript a continuación, si necesitáis mas parte de mi código, hacedmelo saber y lo paso (el json no lo colocó debido a que contiene una cantidad de datos inmensa y se repiten mas que nada).

La linea de codigo donde esta el botón es la siguiente:
fila.insertCell().innerHTML = `<input type='submit' value='seleccionar' class='bg-secondary boton-seleccionar' data-code=${objetoJSON[i].id} data-code=${objetoJSON[i].name.english}>`;

```js
//LLAMADA POKEDEX.JSON
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        document.getElementById("boton-json").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            let boton_seleccionar = '';
            let idPokemon = document.getElementById("identificador").value;
            let nombrePokemon = document.getElementById("pokemon").value;
            //console.log("Comprobación de que el botón json funciona")
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    procesarRespuestaJSON1(this.responseText, idPokemon, nombrePokemon);
                } else if (this.readyState == 4) {
                    console.error('Error al hacer la petición: ' + this.status);
                }
            }
            xhr.open('GET', 'data/pokedex.json', true);
            xhr.send();
        });

    });


    //MOSTRAR TODOS LOS POKEMON | MOSTRAR POR NOMBRE | MOSTRAR POR ID | IGNORAR ID - MOSTRAR NOMBRE
    function procesarRespuestaJSON1(respuesta, idPokemon, nombrePokemon) {
        let objetoJSON = JSON.parse(respuesta);
        let tabla = document.createElement('table');
        tabla.innerHTML = "<thead class='border border-white'><tr class='border border-white'><th class='border border-white'>ID</th><th class='border border-white'>Nombre</th><th class='border border-white'>Tipos</th><th class='border border-white'>Opciones</th></tr></thead>";

        //RECORREMOS LA POKEDEX Y VAMOS CUMPLIENDO SEGÚN LAS CONDICIONES
        for (var i = 0; i < objetoJSON.length; i++) {
            //MOSTRAMOS TODOS SI AMBOS CAMPOS ESTAN VACIOS
            if ((nombrePokemon == '') && (idPokemon == '')) {
                var fila = tabla.insertRow()
                fila.insertCell().innerText = objetoJSON[i].id
                fila.insertCell().innerText = objetoJSON[i].name.english
                fila.insertCell().innerText = objetoJSON[i].type
                fila.insertCell().innerHTML = `<input type='submit' value='seleccionar' class='bg-secondary boton-seleccionar' data-code=${objetoJSON[i].id} data-code=${objetoJSON[i].name.english}>`;
                //MOSTRAMOS EL POKEMON INDICADO SEGÚN EL NOMBRE
            } else if ((idPokemon == '') && (objetoJSON[i].name.english == nombrePokemon)) {
                var fila = tabla.insertRow()
                fila.insertCell().innerText = objetoJSON[i].id
                fila.insertCell().innerText = objetoJSON[i].name.english
                fila.insertCell().innerText = objetoJSON[i].type
                fila.insertCell().innerHTML = `<input type='submit' value='seleccionar' class='bg-secondary boton-seleccionar' data-code=${objetoJSON[i].id} data-code=${objetoJSON[i].name.english}>`;
                //MOSTRAMOS LOS POKEMONS SEGÚN HASTA EL ID INDICADO
            } else if ((objetoJSON[i].id <= idPokemon) && (nombrePokemon == '')) {
                var fila = tabla.insertRow()
                fila.insertCell().innerText = objetoJSON[i].id
                fila.insertCell().innerText = objetoJSON[i].name.english
                fila.insertCell().innerText = objetoJSON[i].type
                fila.insertCell().innerHTML = `<input type='submit' value='seleccionar' class='bg-secondary boton-seleccionar' data-code=${objetoJSON[i].id} data-code=${objetoJSON[i].name.english}>`;
                //MOSTRAMOS EL POKEMON SEGÚN SU NOMBRE E IGNORANDO EL CAMPO ID
            } else if ((idPokemon) && (nombrePokemon)) {
                if (objetoJSON[i].name.english == nombrePokemon) {
                    var fila = tabla.insertRow()
                    fila.insertCell().innerText = objetoJSON[i].id
                    fila.insertCell().innerText = objetoJSON[i].name.english
                    fila.insertCell().innerText = objetoJSON[i].type
                    fila.insertCell().innerHTML = `<input type='submit' value='seleccionar' class='bg-secondary boton-seleccionar' data-code=${objetoJSON[i].id} data-code=${objetoJSON[i].name.english}>`;
                }

            }
        }
        $('.boton-seleccionar').click(function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log("pinchado");
        })
        document.getElementById("contenedor").innerHTML = tabla.outerHTML;

    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>POKEDEX - PRÁCTICA 3</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/styles.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="styles/img/icono-pagina.png" type="image/ico" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="portada" class="my-row ">
        <div class="container fluid padding-portada">
            <div class="row text-center align-items-center">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <img src="styles/img/logopokemon.png" class="img-fluid aumento">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <script>
                        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
                            let myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
                            myAudio.onplaying = function () {
                                isPlaying = true;
                            };
                            myAudio.onpause = function () {
                                isPlaying = false;
                            };
                        });
                        let isPlaying = false;

                        function togglePlay() {
                            if (isPlaying) {
                                myAudio.pause()
                            } else {
                                myAudio.play();
                            }
                        }
                    </script>
                    <audio id="myAudio" src="./styles/music/musica.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>

                    <a class="btn" role="button" onClick="togglePlay()">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="35" height="35" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-play-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM6.79 5.093A.5.5 0 0 0 6 5.5v5a.5.5 0 0 0 .79.407l3.5-2.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.814l-3.5-2.5z" />
                        </svg></a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="interfaz" class="my-row ">
        <div class="container fluid padding-interfaz">
            <div class="row text-center align-items-center">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" role="img" width="1em" height="1em"
                        preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path
                            d="M12 2a10 10 0 0 1 10 10a10 10 0 0 1-10 10A10 10 0 0 1 2 12A10 10 0 0 1 12 2m0 2c-4.08 0-7.45 3.05-7.94 7h4.07c.44-1.73 2.01-3 3.87-3c1.86 0 3.43 1.27 3.87 3h4.07c-.49-3.95-3.86-7-7.94-7m0 16c4.08 0 7.45-3.05 7.94-7h-4.07c-.44 1.73-2.01 3-3.87 3c-1.86 0-3.43-1.27-3.87-3H4.06c.49 3.95 3.86 7 7.94 7m0-10a2 2 0 0 0-2 2a2 2 0 0 0 2 2a2 2 0 0 0 2-2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2z"
                            fill="currentColor" /></svg>
                    <label for="numero" class="texto">Introduce el ID:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="identificador" name="identificador" placeholder="ID del Pokemon" min="1">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" role="img" width="1em" height="1em"
                        preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path
                            d="M12 2a10 10 0 0 1 10 10a10 10 0 0 1-10 10A10 10 0 0 1 2 12A10 10 0 0 1 12 2m0 2c-4.08 0-7.45 3.05-7.94 7h4.07c.44-1.73 2.01-3 3.87-3c1.86 0 3.43 1.27 3.87 3h4.07c-.49-3.95-3.86-7-7.94-7m0 16c4.08 0 7.45-3.05 7.94-7h-4.07c-.44 1.73-2.01 3-3.87 3c-1.86 0-3.43-1.27-3.87-3H4.06c.49 3.95 3.86 7 7.94 7m0-10a2 2 0 0 0-2 2a2 2 0 0 0 2 2a2 2 0 0 0 2-2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2z"
                            fill="currentColor" /></svg>
                    <label for="nombre" class="texto">Introduce el nombre:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="pokemon" name="pokemon" placeholder="Nombre del Pokemon">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <button id="boton-json">Cargar JSON</button>
                    <button id="boton-mostrar">Mostrar seleccionados</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="interfaz" class="my-row ">
        <div class="container fluid">
            <div class="row text-center align-items-center">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <button onClick="window.location.reload();" class="mt-4">Refresh Page</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="zona-pokemon" class="my-row mt-4">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center align-items-center">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div id="contenedor" class="tabla">

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: y el html? coloca completo tu codigo para ayudarte mejor

Comment: Listo, colocado el html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás tratando de ejecutar una acción con un botón que `JS` no conoce porque aún no está creado en el DOM. Cuando por fin se crea, no puede encontrar ningún evento.

Posibles soluciones:

- Ubicar esta línea `document.getElementById("contenedor").innerHTML = tabla.outerHTML;` antes del código `$('.boton-seleccionar').click(function(event){...}`
- Sacar el fragmento `$('.boton-seleccionar').click(function(event){...}` de la función `procesarRespuestaJSON1(...)` a una función independiente y asignar el evento `onclick="botonSeleccionar()"` en los botones con clase `.boton-seleccionar`.

```
function botonSeleccionar() {
    console.log("pinchado");
}
```

- Sacar el fragmento `$('.boton-seleccionar').click(function(event){...}` de la función `procesarRespuestaJSON1(...)` a una función independiente y ejecutar la nueva función después de haber creado todos los elementos del DOM.

```
function procesarRespuestaJSON1(respuesta, idPokemon, nombrePokemon) {
    ...
    botonSeleccionar();
}

function botonSeleccionar() {
    $('.boton-seleccionar').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("pinchado");
    })
}
```

Intenta y comenta si surgen dudas al respecto.

Comment: ¡El botón por fin reacciona, muchisimas gracias de verdad!, lo he conseguido con la primera opción que propusiste, ubicarlo antes de la linea $('.boton-seleccionar').click(function(event){...} . Me estaba volviendo loco ya y estaba bloqueado mentalmente.